# Matching JdbcTemplate update method with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, junit4, mockito

I am trying to match this method which I have used in my Dao class. But I always get the following exception indicating that the call was not made on the method.

It's either the method is not matched, or I am doing something wrong.

```
String pSql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
Object[] pArgs = new Object[] {""};
int[] pArgTypes =  new int[] {};

/* Return 1 when the call to update() is made indicating a successful database update */
when(mJdbcTemplate.update(anyString(), aryEq(pArgs), aryEq(pArgTypes))).thenReturn(1);
```

Here is the stack trace of the exception:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
jdbcTemplate.update(<any>, <any>, <any>);
-> at com.test.GenericDaoJdbcImplTest$WhenInsertUpdateDeleteIsCalledWith.successfulUpdateShouldReturnTrue(GenericDaoJdbcImplTest.java:197)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at com.test.GenericDaoJdbcImplTest.insertUpdateDelete(GenericDaoJdbcImpl.java:121)

    at org.mockito.exceptions.Reporter.wantedButNotInvoked(Reporter.java:269)
    at org.mockito.internal.verification.checkers.MissingInvocationChecker.check(MissingInvocationChecker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.verification.Times.verify(Times.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.verification.MockAwareVerificationMode.verify(MockAwareVerificationMode.java:21)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockHandler.handle(MockHandler.java:80)
    at org.mockito.internal.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$92326890.update(<generated>)
    at com.test.GenericDaoJdbcImplTestTest$WhenInsertUpdateDeleteIsCalledWith.successfulUpdateShouldReturnTrue(GenericDaoJdbcImplTest.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

My `GenericDaoJdbcImplTest` is an abstract class. Here is the class which I am testing.

```
public abstract class GenericDaoJdbcImpl<MODEL, PRIMARYKEY extends Serializable>
        implements GenericJdbcDao<MODEL, PRIMARYKEY> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "jdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate mJdbcTemplate;

    private Class<MODEL> mType;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return mJdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(final JdbcTemplate pJdbcTemplate) {
        this.mJdbcTemplate = pJdbcTemplate;
    }

    public GenericDaoJdbcImpl(final Class<MODEL> pType) {
        this.mType = pType;
    }

    public abstract MODEL add(final MODEL mModel);

    public abstract MODEL modify(final MODEL mModel);

    public abstract MODEL read(PRIMARYKEY pId);

    public abstract List<MODEL> list();

    public abstract void delete(PRIMARYKEY pId);

    @Override
    public boolean insertUpdateDelete(final String pSql, final Object[] pArgs,
            final int[] pArgTypes) {

        Assert.hasLength(pSql, "No SQL provided to execute");
        Assert.notNull(pArgs, "No data provided to insert/update/delete");
        Assert.notNull(pArgTypes, "No data types provided for");
        Assert.isTrue(pArgs.length == pArgTypes.length, "Mis-match in data and data type count");

        return (mJdbcTemplate.update(pSql, pArgs, pArgTypes) > 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an `ArgumentCaptor`, these conditions tend to be less restrictive and allow for validating complex arguments after the call.

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<Object[]> objCap;
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<int[]> intCap;

when(mJdbcTemplate.update(anyString(), objCap.capture(), intCap.capture())).thenReturn(1);
```

Comment: Aah. Why didn't I think of those. Let me try those. Thanks.

Comment: If `jdbcTemplate.update(<any>, <any>, <any>)` is not being invoked, as the stack trace suggests, then using an `ArgumentCaptor` isn't going to help in any way.

Answer (score 6):

You have to cast the arguments in your `when` call.  Otherwise the arguments will be ambiguous and the compiler is unable to resolve it to a specific `update` method.

So:

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.update((String)Mockito.anyString(), (Object[])Mockito.anyVararg())).thenReturn(var);
```

should resolve your issue.  At least it did for me.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I was banging my head because of this for the last two days.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't mock type you don't own!** That's one of the big principle. Mocking these types have a a negative impact the the tests in more than just one way :

1. It complexify your test, potentially making it difficult to craft, read, understand or refactor
2. You have to understand how is used this type.
3. It augments the coupling of the test with this implementation, version, etc
4. It gives you a false sense of security, because you have mokced the behavior so the test is passing, but the real code might have changed the behavior or see new behavior for a new version, and then you'll see a boom on the server!

In your case you are testing something at the boundary of your system, so the thumb rule would be to write **integration test** when dealing with databases, etc. and write **unit test** for your business code.

I heavily recommend the [Growing Object Oriented Software - Guided by tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627) book. I think it's probably one of the most useful book to help write good software using TDD. Plus it has been written by the authors of the first mock framework, *Steve Freeman* and *Nat Pryce*.

Comment: Ok. But what if the ````JdbcTemplate```` is replaced with a separate business class. I mean I want to why the matching is not happening? The code detects that the separate method call was made on a similar method, but it doesn't match that. Why so?

Comment: One of the main reasons to use mocks is to mock classes you don't own that might have complex code that is difficult to exercise every path. This allows you to exercise all options specified by the API. The point of a Unit test is that you test the component in isolation. This doesn't mean in isolation of everything but what you own. Also, I disagree with your statement that this makes tests more difficult, I find it much easier to understand setting a mock to do X than setting up all 15 conditions that drive the class to do X.

Comment: I agree with @JohnB. I don't know about the principles; well not all. But the whole purpose of Unit testing is testing the class in isolation. And if I don't mock out the JdbcTemplate, then I have to setup a dummy database or use hsqldb to run my unit testing, which essentially violates the basic principle of "Unit" testing.

Comment: @divinedragon Yeah precisely I recommend for these kind of test an integration test, not a unit test. I've seen more harm done to a project in the long run when trying to mock types not owned precisely for the reason I quoted. Also test isolation is not a valid argument, as isolation doesn't have to be adapted to the test being done, for unit test you'd want to isolate unwanted behavior for collaborators, for integration test you'd want to isolate unwanted behavior at higher level.

Comment: @JohnB That principle is not a hard line, but ignoring it often, you'll obtain poorly designed code, with tight coupling between test, business and dependency. Instead of focusing time on this I'd rather ensure the whole behavior with the external lib/system is correct than ensuring the interactions match what is written in the code. About fixture this a different topic, integration tests don't always need that *15 conditions*. If you search google about *don't mock type you don't own* you'll find a few stories about guys that tried and failed, and on the mockito mailinglist just as much.