# JdbcTemplate Query Junit Test

Tags: junit, jdbctemplate

I have to write Junit Tests for jdbcTemplate queries for the following methods.
Can anybody help me?

I don't have idea to write the test case for the same. I tried as per Google search but didn't get related solution.

**Method1:**

```
public int savePreBookDetails(String orderId, String preBookAmount, String prodId, String status, String userName, String locationId) {
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertOrder, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(prodId));
                ps.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(preBookAmount));
                ps.setString(3, userName);
                ps.setString(4, status);
                ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(locationId));
                ps.setString(6, orderId);
                return ps;
            }, keyHolder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error during saving prebook with prodId {} and locationId {} ", prodId,locationId + e);
            throw e;
        }
        return (int) keyHolder.getKeys().get("id");
    }
```

**Method 2:**

```
public String findPreBookAmountByOrderId(String orderId) {
        try {
            List<String> list = jdbcTemplate.query(findPreBookAmountByOrderId, (rs, rowNum) -> rs.getString("preBookAmount"), orderId);
            LOGGER.info("Executed query : " + findPreBookAmountByOrderId);
            return list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Error in finding the preBookAmount of orderId {}", orderId + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this help you?query method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562975/how-to-mock-jdbctemplate-query-with-rs-as-an-argument-in-query-method and update method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695056/matching-jdbctemplate-update-method-with-mockito